# Transitivity of "being the zero locus of a section of a vector bundle"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $Z\subset Y\subset X$ be smooth projective $k$-varieties. Suppose $Z$ (resp. $Y$) is defined in $X$ by the vanishing of a section of a vector bundle $E$ (resp. $F$). Is it true that $Z\subset Y$ is also given by the vanishing of a section of a vector bundle on $Y$ ?

Comment: You probably want to assume that the dimensions are right, e.g. $Y\subset X$ is the zero locus of a section of a vector bundle of rank $\mathrm{codim}(Y,X)$.

Comment: This does not sound like "transitivity".  It sounds more like "cancellation".

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is an epimorphism $E \to F$ that takes the section $s \in \Gamma(X,E)$ defining $Z$ to the section $t \in \Gamma(X,F)$ defining $Y$ (this is true under some reasonable assumptions). Let $G$ be the kernel. Then the restriction $s\vert_Y \in \Gamma(Y,E\vert_Y)$ when projected to $\Gamma(Y,F\vert_Y)$ is zero, hence comes from a section $u \in \Gamma(Y,G\vert_Y)$.
Clearly, the zero locus of $u$ on $Y$ equals $Z$.